# Javascript array validation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array, one is normal string array, another one is object array like below:

```
listOfObjects[
  { "name": "A", "data": "[{'value1':'1','value2':'2'}]" },
  { "name": "B", "data": "[{'value1':'','value2':''}]" }
]
stringArray["A","B","C"]
```

How can i compare this two array and return the the stringArray that are not exist in the listOfObjects. Take this for example, it will return "C" cause it does not exist in listOfObjects.

Besides, I also want it to check the listofObjects and return the name if the data.value1 or data.value2 is empty.For example, return "B".

Comment: how would it return 'B' and 'C'?

Comment: @AmberBeriwal listOfObjects.data is empty or values in listOfObjects.data === "",now clear?

Comment: shouldn't it return only "C" as the first condition is not met.

Answer (score 0):

To get the values in `stringArray` which doesn't exist in `listOfObjects`, you can use `array#find` and iterate through each value and using `array#find` check if it exists in `listOfObjects`.

```js
var listOfObjects = [{ "name": "A", "data": "[{'value1':'1','value2':'2'}]" }, { "name": "B", "data": "[{'value1':'','value2':''}]" } ],
    stringArray = ["A", "B", "C"],
    result = stringArray.find(word => !listOfObjects.find(({name}) => name === word));
console.log(result);
```

To find out all the object which have the empty string in data value, you can use `array#filter` to iterate through `listOfObjects` and check if it exists in `stringArray` and after which you can parse the data and check for each value to be the empty string.

```js
var listOfObjects = [ { "name": "A", "data": "[{'value1':'1','value2':'2'}]" }, { "name": "B", "data": "[{'value1':'','value2':''}]" } ],
    stringArray = ["A","B","C"],
    result = listOfObjects.filter(({name, data}) => {
      return stringArray.includes(name) && JSON.parse(data.replace(/'/g,'"')).every(obj => Object.keys(obj).every(key => !obj[key]));
    }).map(({name}) => name);
console.log(result);
```